# angular nvd3 xAxisTickFormatFunction updating the data which I do not want

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have two functions been used in the angular nvd3. They are xAxisTickFormatFunction and toolTipContentFunction.

```
 $scope.xAxisTickFormatFunction = function() {
   return function(d) {
          return d3.time.format("%b, %Y")(new Date(d));
        };
  }

  $scope.toolTipContentFunction = function() {
    return function(d) {
      return  d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")(new Date(d));
    }
  }
```

which d in both function refers to the same value. The original value of d is a date type like "2014-06-20", but after been used in xAxisTickFormatFunction, it turned out to be "June, 2014", and then in the toolTipContentFunction, it's value will be showed as "2014-06-01" instead of "2014-06-20", which implied that the data is missing because of the use of formatting.
How can I avoid the data been updated?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out although the value of d is changed, but we can access the d property from the argument x, which the value of property d has not been updated.

```
  $scope.toolTipContentFunction = function() {
    return function(d, x) {
      return  d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")(new Date(x.point.d));
    }
  }
```

The following are the example code for how to use toolTipContentFunction in the angular nvd3 directives examples from http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html.

```
$scope.toolTipContentFunction = function(){
    return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
        return  'Super New Tooltip' +
            '<h1>' + key + '</h1>' +
            '<p>' +  y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
    }
}
```